# Python-Imap: retrieve MIMEMultipart's mails and get the body with HTML tags

Tags: python, html, email, tags, imap

Here my situation: I am currently retrieving all my outlook (2016) mails from my Inbox, and more specificcaly I am retrieving a table:

```
¦ Product ¦ Currency ¦ Tenor (months) ¦  Code 1 ¦   
¦ MyItem  ¦  USD     ¦   12           ¦ AAA01   ¦
```

My goal is to catch the body of each of them to then store them in a MsSQL Server.

I had difficulties to understand the '**Multipart**' term, now with couples of (long) hours it's more clear.

So for now my process is:

- going through all my mails in the Inbox
- Creating a list of mails' Id
- For all the Id I have in this list, I am checking if the mail is a `Multipart` one.

  - If **Yes** -> I retrieve the body with `body = part.get_payload(decode=True)`
  - If **No** -> I retrieve the body with `body = b.get_payload(decode=True)`

So in both case I use the `get_payload(decode=True)`.

When my mail is "**Multipart**", it appears in my debugger as a simple text:

```
Product
Currency
Tenor (months)
Code 1

MyItem  
USD
12
AAA01
```

When my mail isn't a **Multipart**, it appears in my debugger with **HTML tags**:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"></head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Product</b></td>
            <td><b>Currency</b></td>
            <td><b>Tenor (months)</b></td>
            <td><b>Code 1</b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>MyItem</td>
            <td>USD</td>
            <td>12</td>
            <td>AAA01</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I retrieve body of Multipart's mails with HTML tag also and not as simple text ?

I need HTML tag to identify each header and its corresponding value to use Beautiful Soup and Insert all those data into my MSSQL Server ?

Thanks for your help to let me understand better MIMEMultipart !

Here my (messy) python code:

```
@app.route('/ps_rfq_imap', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
```

def ps_rfq_imap():

```
#Connection to IMAP/OULTLOOK
url = 'outlook.mycompayny.com'
mailbox = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(url,993)
user,password = ('mymail@mycompany.com','mypassword')
mailbox.login(user,password)

mailbox.list() # Lists all labels in GMail
mailbox.select('INBOX') # Connected to inbox.

#giving list id, not outlook ones, but uid ones
typ, data = mailbox.search(None,'ALL') 
#Get all the uid outlook of all emails
#typ, data =    mailbox.uid('search', None,'ALL')
ids = data[0]
id_list = ids.split()
print id_list
#get the most recent email id
latest_email_id = int( id_list[-1] )

for i in range( latest_email_id, latest_email_id-(latest_email_id), -1 ):
    print 'EMAIL ID:'
    print i
    typ, data = mailbox.fetch( i, '(RFC822)')
    msg=str(email.message_from_string(data[0][1]))


    b = email.message_from_string(msg)
    body = ""

    if b.is_multipart():
        email_from = b['from']
        email_subject = b['subject']
        print 'FROM:'
        print email_from
        print 'SUBJECT'
        print email_subject
        for part in b.walk():
            ctype = part.get_content_type()
            cdispo = str(part.get('Content-Disposition'))

            # skip any text/plain (txt) attachments
            if ctype == 'text/plain' and 'attachment' not in cdispo:

                body = part.get_payload(decode=True)  # decode
                print    '******************************* MULTIPART body content***********************************'
                print body 
                break
            elif ctype == 'text/html':
                print 'HTML PART'
                continue
            # not multipart - i.e. plain text, no attachments, keeping fingers crossed
    else:
        email_from = b['from']
        email_subject = b['subject']
        print 'FROM:'
        print email_from
        print 'SUBJECT'
        print email_subject
        body = b.get_payload(decode=True)
        print   '******************************* SIMMMMMMPPPPLLLLEEEE***********************************'
        print body 

return body
```

**EDIT**: here myupdated code to only catch the HTML part of my email, in case it can help somebody:

```
typ, data = mailbox.fetch( i, '(RFC822)')
    msg=str(email.message_from_string(data[0][1]))


    b = email.message_from_string(msg)
    body = ""

    if b.is_multipart():
        email_from = b['from']
        email_subject = b['subject']
        for part in b.walk():
            ctype = part.get_content_type()
            cdispo = str(part.get('Content-Disposition'))
            # skip any text/plain (txt) attachments
            if ctype == 'text/plain' and 'attachment' not in cdispo:
                continue

            elif ctype == 'text/html':
                print 'HTML PART'

                body = part.get_payload(decode=True)  # decode

                soup = BeautifulSoup(body)

                metaTag = soup.find_all('meta')

                if metaTag is not None:
                    print 'WE HAVE FOUND THE BODY******************** Time to process it with BS for getting the value of the table'
                    soup = BeautifulSoup(body, "html.parser")
                    tables = soup.findChildren('table')


                continue
            # not multipart - i.e. plain text, no attachments, keeping fingers crossed
    else:
        continue
```

Best Regards,

Comment: Look at the Content-Type of each part, don't just guess which part to grab.  You want the one that has type "text/html".

Comment: You showed me exactly what I was missing ! thanks a lot !!!

Comment: Post solutions as answers and accept them!

Comment: I am still new here, how do I do that ? I can't upvote your first comment :)